# Angular chart.js onClick is not working - how to get all elements of a bar when it is clicked on

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, bar-chart, chart.js

I am a beginner to Chart.js and I am trying to create click events when a chart is created.

I am trying to access all the elements of a bar when it is clicked on, but right now, the onClick method is not even running properly. The chart is rendering just fine - any html should not be needed as the canvas is created in the code. I would appreciate help in order to solve this problem

```
controller($state, $scope, $rootScope) {
    $scope.myChart;
```

....

```
    $scope.go = function myFunc() {
      document.getElementById("chartContainer").innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
      document.getElementById("chartContainer").innerHTML = '<canvas style="margin-top: 10px; padding-top: 20px; height:90% ; background-color: ' + vm.options.backgroundColor + '; " id="myChart" click="onClick"></canvas>';
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');

       render($scope.myChart, ctx, vm.options.barColor, vm.options.backgroundColor, labelVal, value);
  };
  $scope.onClick = function (evt) {
    console.log("Testing"); 
  };

}
var render = function createChart(myChart, ctx, barColor, backgroundColor, labels, values) {


myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',

    data: {
        labels: labels,
        datasets: [{
            backgroundColor: barColor,

            data: values,
                }]

    },
    options: {
        events: ['click'],
        chartArea: {
            backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
        },
        global: {
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
        },
        scaleBeginAtZero: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,

        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    autoSkip: false,
                }
                }],
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true,
                    min: 0
                }
                    }]
        }
    }
});

}
```

Comment: the thing is I am regenerating the chart over and over again based on user input, and that is causing the chart to be glitchy, triggering hover events in previous charts created on the same canvas. myChart.destroy() prevented any charts from being shown, so the most recommended and effective option was to delete and recreate the canvas

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TRY adding the following on-click event handler in your chart options ...

```
options: {
   onClick: function(e) {
      var element = this.getElementAtEvent(e);
      if (element.length) {
         console.log(element[0])
      }
   },
   ...
}
```

<sup>This should work as far as I can tell</sup>

Comment: Thank You so much, this worked, and now I can get the index of the bar in the chart

Comment: I have the same question!